# Link style not working

Tags: css

Okay so I just want my links to have a border-bottom.

This is my code:

```
<div class="intro">jfskdlq kflsdq jklfjsqd <a href="google.be" title="website" target="_blank">website</a></div><p>jqskdlfjklqsjklmqjfkdlksqlmlmdfsqlmqsdf</p>

.intro {
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: 7px 16px 7px 16px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: #cfffef;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.intro a, .intro a:visited {
    color: #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 1px #ffffff;
}
```

However, only the color: #cccccc shows, not the border-bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
border-bottom: 1px #ffffff;
```

This doesn't show anything because the default value of `border-style` is **`none`**.

Therefore, you probably want to be applying a style if you actually want to see any results.

Here's an example:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
```

I'm using `solid` as the example `border-style`, but it could be any from [**a range of styles**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style).

See more about the `border-bottom` shorthand [**here**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-bottom).

Here's the [**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QupUj/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add the border style, (i.e., solid, etc.) to your border-bottom rule.

Answer (score 0):

How about `text-decoration: underline`?

Using `border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;` -> notice the `solid` addition to your declaration, is all fine but when it comes to making text (anchored links like you got there) you want to use an underline.

Border-bottom will only apply to the outside box of the text. So if you have a paragraph of text only the very last line of text will be "bordered" while an underline - creates a border on all the text.

## Code REvision

```
.intro a, .intro a:visited {
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```